# Simple Query using sqlite 3, php and PDO fails

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

This is first post of a question. Tried to find an answer here, but all relevant posts seems dated or use deprecated mysql.

New to sqlite, so forgive what might appear stupid, but the query in the code below never works. Note: we are running sqlite3 and PDO on site with php 5.6.
A Program to create the db worked fine. And the app "Db Browser for SQL Lite" shows DB and tables and data just fine. But this:

```
<?php
//open the database
$myPDO = new PDO('sqlite:MySqlitedb1');
print "<p>db opened</p>";
$result = $myPDO->query('SELECT * FROM users');

//if the query works
if ($result !== FALSE) {
   print "<p>query ran</p>";   
   foreach($result as $row){
   print "<p>".$row."</p>"; 
   }  
 } else {
 // when the query fails
 print "<p>query failed</p>"; 
}  //end if

// close the database connection
$myPDO = NULL;
?>
```

Always results in a 'query failed'. Queries for specific records that ARE there also fails.

Also Tried some other testing in code above using fetch and fetchall, and they generated errors like:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() 
on boolean in (path emoved)/testpdo2.php on line 27
```

Which I am sure was caused by the fact the query fails so $result is null/false
I am obviously missing something stupid here?

Joe C.

Comment: How are you ensuring that you're using the correct directory?

Answer (score 2):

This is solved. The code should have worked (it does now). It was not

> - a directory issue
> - a permissions issue
> - a debug_kit.sqlite file in the tmp directory, or any files in the tmp dir.
> - a SCP or 'sync' directory issue

I altered the code and trapped an exception (1st with 'bad' DB then good one):

```
<?php

$myPDO = NULL;              //close db just in case...

//open the database
$myPDO = new PDO('sqlite:newsqlite2.db');

//throw exceptions
$myPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if ($myPDO != null)
    print "<p>db connected</p>";
else
    print "<p>db did not connect</p>";
// result: db does open

//1st test
try
{
     $result0=$myPDO->query('SELECT * from  users');
     print "<p>query ran</p>";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
     echo "Statement failed: " . $e->getMessage();
     return false;
}

// close the database connection
$myPDO = NULL;

?>
```

This threw an error with the original DB (MySqlitedb1) and an PDO exception:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 11 database disk image is malformed
```

Now, DESPITE analyse tools run on the database saying it was 'fine' and being able to work on the database with tools like "DB Browser for SQLite" without ANY issues, nor having issues creating other DB's, SOMETHING was amiss with the file. This caused the query's to fail and always return as a Boolean 'false', so the code failed.

We fixed the DB by dumping it to a sql file, then importing it (with "DB Browser for SQLite") to create a new database (newsqlite2.db), with the data. Using that DB, the code ran fine, extracted data etc.

As to why/how the database became "corrupt" or what the weird corruption was, I have not a clue. :)

Joe C.